# How to continue gameplay without page reload

Tags: javascript

I am building a Javascript Rock, Paper, Scissors game and I have to reload the page every time I want to play another "round". Any suggestions on how to continue looping through the game without reloading the page and keeping the score?

```
    var compChoice = "";
var userChoice = "";

//comp choice
compChoice = Math.random();
 if(compChoice < 0.34) {
     compChoice = 'rock';
 }
 else if(compChoice <= 0.67) {
     compChoice = 'paper';
 }
 else {
     compChoice = 'scissors';
};
//compare function
var compare = function(userChoice, compChoice) {
    if(userChoice == compChoice) {
        return("Draw");
    }
    else if(userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
        return("PLayer Wins");
    }
    else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
        return("Player Wins");
    }
    else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
        return("Player Wins");
    }
    else {
        return("Player loses");
    }
};
//click events
$('#rock').click(function() {
    var result = compare('rock', compChoice);
    $('#decision').html(result);

})
$('#paper').click(function() {
    var result = compare('paper', compChoice);
    $('#decision').html(result);
})
$('#scissors').click(function() {
    var result = compare('scissors', compChoice);
    $('#decision').html(result);
})
```

Comment: What does a new "round" look like? Just reset your UI elements and variables to their default state. No need for page refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn the computers choice into a function which returns the value you can then call it every time and get a new value.

```js
var userChoice = "";

//comp choice
var getCompChoice = function() {
   var choice = Math.random();
   if(choice < 0.34) {
       return 'rock';
   }
   else if(choice <= 0.67) {
       return 'paper';
   }
   else {
       return 'scissors';
   }
}

//compare function
var compare = function(userChoice) {
    
    compChoice = getCompChoice();
    
    if(userChoice == compChoice) {
        return("Draw");
    }
    else if(userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
        return(`Player Wins. rock > ${compChoice}`);
    }
    else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
        return(`Player Wins. paper > ${compChoice}`);
    }
    else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
        return(`Player Wins. scissors > ${compChoice}`);
    }
    else {
        return(`Player Looses. ${userChoice} < ${compChoice}`);
    }
};

//click events
$('#rock').click(function() {
    var result = compare('rock');
    $('#decision').html(result);

})
$('#paper').click(function() {
    var result = compare('paper');
    $('#decision').html(result);
})
$('#scissors').click(function() {
    var result = compare('scissors');
    $('#decision').html(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rock">rock</div>
<div id="scissors">scissors</div>
<div id="paper">paper</div>
<div id="decision"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/9uq19dtc/1/.

Basically you just needed to put your `compChoice` code in a place where it gets called for every button click, rather than only when the page loads.

To keep score, just make 2 more divs that have player score and comp score, and increment their values each time one of them wins.

Answer (score 0):

Have your 'click' buttons do the compChoice logic instead of at the beginning, so it chooses a new result whenever you click Rock, Paper, or Scissors:

```
var userChoice = "";

//comp choice
var chooseCompChoice = function() {
  compChoice = Math.random();
  if(compChoice < 0.34) {
    return 'rock';
  }
  else if(compChoice <= 0.67) {
    return 'paper';
  }
  else {
    return 'scissors';
  }
};

//compare function
var compare = function(userChoice, compChoice) {
  if(userChoice === compChoice) {
    return("Draw");
  }
  else if(userChoice === "rock" && compChoice === "scissors") {
    return("Player Wins");
  }
  else if (userChoice === "paper" && compChoice === "rock") {
    return("Player Wins");
  }
  else if (userChoice === "scissors" && compChoice === "paper") {
    return("Player Wins");
  }
  else {
    return("Player loses");
  }
};

//click events
$('#rock').click(function() {
  var compChoice = chooseCompChoice();
  var result = compare('rock', compChoice);
  $('#decision').html(result);
})

$('#paper').click(function() {
  var compChoice = chooseCompChoice();
  var result = compare('paper', compChoice);
  $('#decision').html(result);
})

$('#scissors').click(function() {
  var compChoice = chooseCompChoice();
  var result = compare('scissors', compChoice);
  $('#decision').html(result);
})
```